# how to implement ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, io, client-server, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I need help with implementing an byteArrayOutputStream that stores the output from the server, which I can then read from and print. Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

TCPAsk:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import tcpclient.TCPClient;

public class TCPAsk {
    /*
     * Usage: explain how to use the program, then exit with failure status
     */
    private static void usage() {
        System.err.println("Usage: TCPAsk host port <data to server>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Main program. Parse arguments on command line and call TCPClient
     */
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        String hostname = null;
        int port = 0;
        byte[] userInputBytes = new byte[0];

        try {
            // Get mandatory command line arguments: hostname and port number
            int argindex = 0;
            hostname = args[argindex++];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[argindex++]);

            // Remaining arguments, if any, are string to send to server
            if (argindex < args.length) {
                // Collect remaining arguments into a string with single space as separator
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                boolean first = true;
                while (argindex < args.length) {
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    else
                        builder.append(" ");
                    builder.append(args[argindex++]);
                }
                builder.append("\n");
                userInputBytes = builder.toString().getBytes();
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException ex) {
            // Exceeded array while parsing command line, or could
            // not convert port number argument to integer -- tell user
            // how to use the program
            usage();
        }

        try {
            TCPClient tcpClient = new tcpclient.TCPClient();
            byte[] serverBytes  = tcpClient.askServer(hostname, port, userInputBytes);
            String serverOutput = new String(serverBytes);
            System.out.printf("%s:%d says:\n%s", hostname, port, serverOutput);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: my code is now working and it is similar to the answer (TCPClient) given below with some minor additions. ByteArrayOutputStream is not needed.

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream` *is* 'dynamically changing'. What is your actual question?

Comment: It's an output stream. Write to it. But does this code really produce this output? It looks exactly the same as your previous, working, version except for the unused `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Your previous code printed everything the server sent. So does this code, it being the same. I don't understand what you're asking. Nor what `ByteArrayOutputStream` has to do with it. You don't need it, you have other working code.

Comment: Write to the Output stream, read from the input stream. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't send the user data to the server. Just modify `TCPClient` like this:

```
package tcpclient;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TCPClient
{
    public TCPClient()
    {}

    public byte[] askServer(String hostname, int port, byte[] toServerBytes) throws IOException
    {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);

        byte[] bufferSize = new byte[1000];

        //send message to the server
        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(toServerBytes);

        // Query response
        String response;
        // Length of response
        int responseLength;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((responseLength = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(bufferSize)) != -1)
        {
            response = new String(bufferSize, 0, responseLength, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            sb.append(response);
        }

        clientSocket.close();
        return sb.toString().getBytes();
    }
```